# Jenkins - Project based authorization and LDAP

Tags: ldap, jenkins, authorization

Does anybody know if the *Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy* is supposed to work with LDAP integration?

There are several closed bug reports on [JENKINS-2324](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-2324) that say users don't need to have global read access and they can still get in to see a single project but that doesn't seem to be working with LDAP enabled, or maybe there's something else I'm doing wrong?

The first answer from [restrict view of jobs per-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323129/jenkins-restrict-view-of-jobs-per-user) on Stack Overflow doesn't work for me with LDAP (you can read my post on the linked JENKINS-2324 above for more detail as well):

> Short description without screenshots: Use Jenkins "Project-based
>   Matrix Authorization Strategy" under "Manage Jenkins" => "Configure
>   System". On the configuration page of each project, you now have
>   "Enable project-based security". Now add each user you want to
>   authorize.